# BibTeX article entries and their common journal

Tags: bibtex

I want to cite multiple articles from the same journal issue. So I thought that having one BibTeX entry for the journal issue and then cross-referencing it from each article's entry would be the proper way to go. What is the right entry type to use for the journal issue?

I'd like to have something like this:

```
@article{foo1,
  title="a",
  author="b",
  crossref="foo"
}

@journal{foo,
  booktitle="The Foo Journal",
  editor="Wong SCNR Foo",
  year=1970,
  publisher="Foo Associates"
}
```

The problem is that there is no "journal" entry type.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I understand your setup correctly, the entries of type  `@article` only have the fields `journal`, `year`,`volume`, and `number` in common. By creating a common cross-reference you'll save four lines per entry, but then you have to add one line (the `crossref` field) for each of these entries -- *and* you also have to create a new entry that contains the information that's common to all the other entries. Is it worth the trouble? You do the math...

Comment: I like to follow the DRY principle. If I have an error in any of the shared fields I'd have to fix it in all affected entries. Having one common cross-reffed entry would get that down to fixing it at one place only. Also: what's the difference between a journal and a proceedings?

Comment: You can do something similar with `inproceedings` cross-referencing a `proceedings` entry. This however requires `title` and `booktitle`. If this does not destroy the generated bibliography and you can live with a warning from Bibtex and possibly an individual entry for the whole issue in your bibliography, you could do it. I recently had this idea, too, but decided against it, because I want the `bib` to be usable for journal submissions and cannot guarantee such a setup to work. If supporting third-party styles was not an issue, I would use `@Xdata` entry-containers and `biblatex` + `biber`.